# How can I copy an object to a clipboard as a formatted JSON object?

Tags: javascript, json, clipboard

For my current project I have a method that being triggered on context menu and after selection of cells from the table. Basically those values selected are being organized into an object in one method that I have created and I would like to have it copied to the clipboard in a way so when this JSON object is being pasted somewhere else it is nicely formatted (something like that can be done with those objects in Chrome Dev Tools on "copy object" option pressed)

Example of object formatting:

```
{
  "indicatorName": null,
  "instanceGuid": null,
  "facts": {
    "decimals": "2",
    "specialUnit": "Monetary"
  },
  "value": {
    "column": 0,
    "row": 1
  },
  "xAxis": {
    "title": null,
    "value": "Денежные средства и их эквиваленты",
    "indexNumber": null
  },
  "yAxis": {
    "title": null,
    "value": "2020-12-31",
    "indexNumber": null
  },
}
```

Currently I tried using `copy-to-clipboard` library and managed to get an object copied as a string into a clipboard through `copy(JSON.stringify(copiedObj));`, where `copiedObj` is a regular JS object, however the formatting of it is just a string without any spacing or new lines, which I need to do in this case.

Also I tried passing it without `JSON.stringify()` but than just a text `[object Object]` is being copied.

What could I do in this situation in order to achieve the desired formatting? Is there a particular setup that I would need to pass into the `copy` function from this library or is there some better tool that you could suggest using to achieve the desired result?

Comment: to format the JSON you can try this `JSON.stringify(copiedObj, undefined, 2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by Shyam in the comment above adding parameters `undefined` and `2` into `JSON.stringify(copiedObj, undefined, 2)` achieves the desired result